# I am running into a gradient computation inplace error

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I am running this code (https://github.com/ayu-22/BPPNet-Back-Projected-Pyramid-Network/blob/master/Single_Image_Dehazing.ipynb) on a custom dataset but I am running into this error.
`RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an in place operation: [torch. cuda.FloatTensor [1, 512, 4, 4]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!`

[image: Error Message]

Please refer to the code link above for clarification of where the error is occurring.

I am running this model on a custom dataset, the data loader part is pasted below.

```
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
    train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((256,256)),
    #transforms.RandomResizedCrop(256),
    #transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    #transforms.ColorJitter(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.5,0.5,0.5], [0.5,0.5,0.5])
 ])

class Flare(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, flare_dir, wf_dir,transform = None):
    self.flare_dir = flare_dir
    self.wf_dir = wf_dir
    self.transform = transform
    self.flare_img = os.listdir(flare_dir)
    self.wf_img = os.listdir(wf_dir)
    
  def __len__(self):
     return len(self.flare_img)
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    f_img = Image.open(os.path.join(self.flare_dir, self.flare_img[idx])).convert("RGB")
    for i in self.wf_img:
        if (self.flare_img[idx].split('.')[0][4:] == i.split('.')[0]):
            wf_img = Image.open(os.path.join(self.wf_dir, i)).convert("RGB")
            break
    f_img = self.transform(f_img)
    wf_img = self.transform(wf_img)
    
   return f_img, wf_img         





flare_dir = '../input/flaredataset/Flare/Flare_img'
wf_dir = '../input/flaredataset/Flare/Without_Flare_'
flare_img = os.listdir(flare_dir)
wf_img = os.listdir(wf_dir)
wf_img.sort()
flare_img.sort()
print(wf_img[0])
train_ds = Flare(flare_dir, wf_dir,train_transform)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_ds,
                                       batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
                                       shuffle=True)
```

To get a better idea of the dataset class , you can compare my dataset class with the link pasted above

Comment: Which version of PyTorch you are using to run this code? Are you using Colab?

Comment: Kaggle. Thanks for the answer, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is stuck in what is called the "Backpropagation" of your GAN Network.

What you have defined your backward graph should follow is the following:

```
def backward(self, unet_loss, dis_loss):
        dis_loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
        self.dis_optimizer.step()

        unet_loss.backward()
        self.unet_optimizer.step()
```

So in your backward graph, you are propagating the `dis_loss` which is the combination of the discriminator and adversarial loss first and then you are propagating the `unet_loss` which is the combination of `UNet`, `SSIM` and `ContentLoss` but the `unet_loss` is connected to discriminator's output loss. So the pytorch is confused and gives you this error as you are taking the optimizer step of `dis_loss` before even storing the backward graph for `unet_loss` and I would recommend you to change the code as follows:

```
def backward(self, unet_loss, dis_loss):
        dis_loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
        unet_loss.backward()

        self.dis_optimizer.step()
        self.unet_optimizer.step()
```

And this will start your training! but you can experiment with your `retain_graph=True`.

And great work on the BPPNet Work.